# how can I split file into newlines using a delimiter?

Tags: string, perl, split, newline, delimiter

Hi I have the following file:

```
>AKJDHDLFNLDNFLNFRFMD
>ALKSJLDKJSAD
>GLHGFNHHOTHJRTKHRNLGKNFKGNHGKHMNFGH
```

and I want to split this file by the '>' symbol to obtain:

```
>
AKJDHDLFNLDNFLNFRFMD
>
ALKSJLDKJSAD
>
GLHGFNHHOTHJRTKHRNLGKNFKGNHGKHMNFGH
```

maybe something in perl/awk? thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0ne 'print join "\n", grep length, split /\n?(>)/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply substitute `>` with `>\n`, e.g.

```
perl -np 's/>/>\n/' file
```